# Does ACL rules applies to events?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have following questions related to events in composer.

Question 1: Can i write a READ acl rule for event to define which participant will receive this event?

Question 2: Is there a way to send events to specific participant?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events are simply serialised and put onto the Hyperledger Fabric event bus. At present HLF doesn't have the concept of topic/queues to segregate the messages on the bus, or rich security policies to determine who can access the events.

Answer (score 1):

At this time ACLs are not applied to Events, and there isn't a way to send events to a specific participant.
However we would really like to know your use cases and requirements in this are so please raise a github issue at
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer 
and of course contributions welcome.